# GTK window goes black when GTK_GL_AREA is present

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl, gtk3, glade

I am building a GUI with GTK3 and I placed `GTK_GL_AREA` in it.

This `GTK_GL_AREA` is connected to some "render" and "realize" signals.

Anyway when I launch the GUI some parts of the window become black as soon as I hover the mouse over the window. 
If, then, I hover the mouse over the button widgets they show up again, but neutral parts of the window remains black.

If I expand the window all shows up for a while, but if I hover the mouse over the window it goes black again.

This phenomenon gets worse when I continuously redraw in the `GTK_GL_AREA` calling `gtk_gl_area_queue_render()` and does not happen when I disable `GTK_GL_AREA signals.`

I attach some [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNNAw.png) to let you understand what I described above.

Hope you could give me some hints to avoid this behaviour.

PS. Even when I saw the full window I needed to overlap another window on the GTK one since pressing the print button it became black just before the screenshot acquisition.

**EDIT**: I am sorry for not having showed you the code in order to reproduce what I meant. The following is a simple code with a GTK_GL_AREA and two buttons. It compiles without any error but when I hover the mouse over one of those buttons some part of the window become [blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBAEd.png) (in this image on the left how the window should appear, on the right how it appears as soon as I pass the mouse on the lower button).

```
//file main.cpp
//to compile -> g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -lGL -lglfw -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtkx.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

/*Signals prototypes*/
void on_upper_button_clicked (GtkButton *b);
void on_lower_button_clicked (GtkButton *b);
void on_realize(GtkGLArea *area);
gboolean render(GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context);


/* Widgets declaration*/

GtkWidget *main_window;
GtkWidget *upper_button;
GtkWidget *lower_button;
GtkGLArea *glarea;
GtkBox *box_gl;

/* GLADE builder*/
GtkBuilder *builder;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("test.ui");

    /* Widgets initialization*/
    main_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "main_window"));
    upper_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "upper_button"));
    lower_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lower_button"));
    glarea = GTK_GL_AREA(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "glarea"));

    /*Signals connection*/
    g_signal_connect(main_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (upper_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_upper_button_clicked), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (lower_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_lower_button_clicked), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (glarea, "realize", G_CALLBACK (on_realize), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (glarea, "render", G_CALLBACK (render), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show(main_window); 

    /*gtk_main*/
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

void on_upper_button_clicked (GtkButton *b)
{
    printf("UP\n");
}
void on_lower_button_clicked (GtkButton *b)
{
    printf("DOWN\n");
}

void on_realize (GtkGLArea *area)
{
    gtk_gl_area_make_current (GTK_GL_AREA (area));
    return;
}

gboolean render(GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
    gtk_gl_area_make_current (GTK_GL_AREA (area));
    gdk_gl_context_make_current (context);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    return TRUE;
}
```

And this is the *.ui code generated with GLADE.

```
<!-- file test.ui --> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box_gl">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="upper_button">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">UP</property>
            <property name="width_request">60</property>
            <property name="height_request">60</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="relief">none</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_upper_button_clicked" swapped="yes"/>
          </object>
        </child> 
        <child>
          <object class="GtkGLArea" id="glarea">
            <property name="width_request">300</property>
            <property name="height_request">210</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="app_paintable">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <signal name="realize" handler="on_realize" swapped="no"/>
            <signal name="render" handler="render" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="lower_button">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">DOWN</property>
            <property name="width_request">60</property>
            <property name="height_request">60</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="relief">none</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_lower_button_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Even with this small code I encounter the problem I reported above. I have a more complex code in which I draw a cube in the GTK_GL_AREA. If needed I will post it too.

[image: shot1]
[image]

Comment: Hi, what GPU and driver are you using? I tried to reproduce the issue but it worked fine on my machine (Intel UHD 620 with Mesa 20.0.7) [see this screenshot](https://imgur.com/JrnLE5K).

Comment: This is the output of 

glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version" : OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 410.108

I don't know how to retrieve info you need.

Comment: My GPU is a NVIDIA RTX 2070

EDIT: with nvidia-smi I obtain the following:

| NVIDIA-SMI 410.108      Driver Version: 410.108      CUDA Version: 10.0     |
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |

Comment: Where's your `glewInit()` call?  Why are you linking in GLUT, GLFW, & GLU?

Comment: Does turning on auto-render via `gtk_gl_area_set_auto_render()` help?

Comment: Tried to add either `glewInit()` and/or `gtk_gl_area_set_auto_render(glarea, TRUE/FALSE)`  but nothing changes.  I am linking in GLUT, GLFW, & GLU because I copied and pasted my main project compiler instrucions, so they are unnecessary but doesn't affect the program behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with another program. Some parsers break unexplainably and its always good to have another. You also could try updating said parser

Comment: What do you mean with 'parser'?